# Transfer Coroutine Dispatcher's Tasks to another Dispatcher

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines

My question is simple, given Dispatcher 1, how would you transfer Dispatcher 1's tasks to another Dispatcher named Dispatcher 2?

Comment: I’m curious about what use case there could be for this.

Comment: Do you mean just switching a coroutine from one dispatcher to another? Or decide at some point in time that all tasks submitted to one dispatcher should be launched by another?

Comment: Switching a coroutine from one dispatcher to another.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Let's say you have a thread pool that executes some tasks for a slave server. What if the slave server dies and you need to move the tasks to another slave server.

Comment: You have to provide more info about the use case, It doesn't sound like something that should be handled at dispatchers level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what transfer would mean but yes you can jump between **threads**. You can use `withContext` within a coroutine to switch between **threads**. Like so:

```
val customContext = newSingleThreadContext("CustomContext")

runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    // Started in DefaultDispatcher
    withContext(customContext) {
        // Working in CustomContext
    }
    // Back to DefaultDispatcher
}
```

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
    // Started in main thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // Working in DefaultDispatcher
    }
    // Back to main thread
}
```